# gym RL with MultiDiscrete ActionSpace AttributeError: 'MultiDiscrete' object has no attribute 'spaces'

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I'm trying to build an Reinforcement Learning Algorithm, which can play the  [MasterMind Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)). I'm using an MultiDiscrete Anction and Observation Space. The Action Space takes 4 slots with 6 colors each and the Observation Space is 2x4. I created an Custom Environment to connect with my programmed game. The Environment isnt ready yet due to the occuring error. Maybe someone can help me solving this issue.

```python
import gym as gym
from gym import Env
from gym.spaces import Discrete, Box, MultiDiscrete, Dict
from stable_baselines3.common.policies import MultiInputActorCriticPolicy

action_space = MultiDiscrete(np.array([6,6,6,6]), dtype=int)
observation_space = MultiDiscrete(np.array([4,4]), dtype=int)

...

class MasterMindEnv(Env):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(MasterMindEnv, self).__init__()
        self.action_space = action_space
        self.observation_space = observation_space

    def step(self, action:np.ndarray):
        pass_action(action)
        output = get_output()
        print(output)

        reward = output[0] + output[1]
        print(reward)
        
        done = False
        info = {}

        return observation_space.sample(), 1, done, info

    def reset(self):
        return self.observation_space.sample()
        
...

model = A2C(MultiInputActorCriticPolicy, env)
model.learn(total_timesteps=1000)
```

And the Error is:

```js
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\...\model.ipynb Zelle 10 in <module>
----> 1 model = A2C(MultiInputActorCriticPolicy, env)
      2 model.learn(total_timesteps=1000)


File c:\...\Python310\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\a2c\a2c.py:126, in A2C.__init__(self, policy, env, learning_rate, n_steps, gamma, gae_lambda, ent_coef, vf_coef, max_grad_norm, rms_prop_eps, use_rms_prop, use_sde, sde_sample_freq, normalize_advantage, tensorboard_log, create_eval_env, policy_kwargs, verbose, seed, device, _init_setup_model)
    123     self.policy_kwargs["optimizer_kwargs"] = dict(alpha=0.99, eps=rms_prop_eps, weight_decay=0)
    125 if _init_setup_model:
--> 126     self._setup_model()

File c:\...\Python310\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\on_policy_algorithm.py:123, in OnPolicyAlgorithm._setup_model(self)
    112 buffer_cls = DictRolloutBuffer if isinstance(self.observation_space, gym.spaces.Dict) else RolloutBuffer
    114 self.rollout_buffer = buffer_cls(
    115     self.n_steps,
    116     self.observation_space,
   (...)
    121     n_envs=self.n_envs,
    122 )
--> 123 self.policy = self.policy_class(  # pytype:disable=not-instantiable
...
--> 258 for key, subspace in observation_space.spaces.items():
    259     if is_image_space(subspace):
    260         extractors[key] = NatureCNN(subspace, features_dim=cnn_output_dim)

AttributeError: 'MultiDiscrete' object has no attribute 'spaces'
```

**UPDATE**

```py
class MasterMindEnv(Env):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(MasterMindEnv, self).__init__()
        self.action_space = MultiDiscrete(np.array([6,6,6,6]), dtype=int)
        self.observation_space = MultiDiscrete(np.array([4,4]), dtype=int)

    def step(self, action:np.ndarray):
        output = observation_space.sample()
        reward = output[0] + output[1]
        done = False
        if (reward == 8):
            done = True
        info = {}
        return output, float(reward), done, info

    def reset(self):
        return self.observation_space.sample()

env = MasterMindEnv()

model = A2C("MlpPolicy", env)
model.learn(total_timesteps=1000)
```

It generates:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\...\model.ipynb Zelle 9 in <module>
      1 model = A2C("MlpPolicy", env)
----> 2 model.learn(total_timesteps=1000)

File c:\...\Python310\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\a2c\a2c.py:203, in A2C.learn(self, total_timesteps, callback, log_interval, eval_env, eval_freq, n_eval_episodes, tb_log_name, eval_log_path, reset_num_timesteps, progress_bar)
    189 def learn(
    190     self: A2CSelf,
    191     total_timesteps: int,
   (...)
    200     progress_bar: bool = False,
    201 ) -> A2CSelf:
--> 203     return super().learn(
    204         total_timesteps=total_timesteps,
    205         callback=callback,
    206         log_interval=log_interval,
    207         eval_env=eval_env,
    208         eval_freq=eval_freq,
    209         n_eval_episodes=n_eval_episodes,
    210         tb_log_name=tb_log_name,
    211         eval_log_path=eval_log_path,
    212         reset_num_timesteps=reset_num_timesteps,
    213         progress_bar=progress_bar,
    214     )
...
--> 464     return th.as_tensor(obs).to(device)
    465 elif isinstance(obs, dict):
    466     return {key: th.as_tensor(_obs).to(device) for (key, _obs) in obs.items()}

RuntimeError: Could not infer dtype of numpy.int32
```

Answer (score 0):

```
observation_space = MultiDiscrete(np.array([4,4]), dtype=int)
...
model = A2C(MultiInputActorCriticPolicy, env)
...
for key, subspace in observation_space.spaces.items():
```

MultiInput should not be needed for a MultiDiscrete space. It is still only one observation space while MultiInput is needed when providing multiple observation spaces.

Either do not use the MultiInput policy (such as with `ActorCriticPolicy`) or wrap the space (such as with `spaces.Tuple`)

```
Stable Baselines3 supports handling of multiple inputs by using Dict Gym space. 
This can be done using MultiInputPolicy, which by default uses the 
CombinedExtractor feature extractor to turn multiple inputs into a single 
vector, handled by the net_arch network.
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed the Policy to 'MlpPolicy'. But this does not take any kid of int data Type . Is there smth I dont see? RuntimeError: Could not infer dtype of numpy.int32 -- in -- return super().learn() -- in -- return th.as_tensor(obs).to(device)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @AR_Jini - Sorry about the delay. You may need to share your updated code. I tried running now the code you have in this post and I do not get any error. (with the policy replaced by "MlpPolicy" and working around the pass_action call).

It looks like it It could be related to the logic in your step method. The error you quoted appears to be about converting the observation you return - not about the policy not accepting values. You should be able to start a debugger at the point of the error.

Comment: @c.lorenz - No Problem, thanks for replying. From my perspective the step function does not do any suspicious stuff. It just uses random values for processing. Debugging doesnt brought any additional information.